# Multiple variables in a Java Switch statement

Tags: java, switch-statement

I'm not a developer but I know there should be a better way of doing the following. I'm not too familiar with lambda expressions but happy to be shown a better way.

I need to set a UK registration plate. Each year can have one of 2 values for the 3rd and 4th digit of the registration plate:
For example: 01/03/2017-31/08/2017 would have '17' e.g. `AE17GHS` whereas 01/09/2017-28/02/2018 would have '67' e.g. `AE67GHS`

```
    public void setVehiclePlateYear(StartDate startDate) {
    
       //Example parameter:
       //String startDate = "2017-06-17";

        String year = startDate.getStartDateString().substring(2, 4);
        String month = startDate.getStartDateString().substring(5, 7);

        switch (month) {
            case "03":
            case "04":
            case "05":
            case "06":
            case "07":
            case "08":
                if (year.equals("15"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "15";
                else if (year.equals("16"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "16";
                else if (year.equals("17"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "17";
                else if (year.equals("18"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "18";
                else if (year.equals("18"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "19";
                else if (year.equals("19"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "20";
                else if (year.equals("20"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "21";
                break;
            case "01":
            case "02":
            case "09":
            case "10":
            case "11":
            case "12":
                if (year.equals("15"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "64";
                else if (year.equals("16"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "65";
                else if (year.equals("17"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "66";
                else if (year.equals("18"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "67";
                else if (year.equals("19"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "69";
                else if (year.equals("20"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "70";
                else if (year.equals("21"))
                    vehiclePlateYear = "71";
                break;
        }

        setPlateDate(vehiclePlateYear);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no idea if your algorithm for generating the plates is correct, but two things:

1. You have a typo in your code where you check if the year is "18" twice.
2. You can rewrite it like this:

```java
case "08": 
    int parsedYear = Integer.valueOf(year);  
    if (parsedYear >= 15 && parsedYear <= 21) {  
        vehiclePlateYear = parsedYear;  
    }
```

Also, I think you can simplify the second big block of if statements like this:

```java
int parsedYear = Integer.valueOf(year);
int base = 64;
int delta = parsedYear - 15;
if (parsedYear >= 15 && parsedYear <= 21) {
    vehiclePlateYear = base + delta;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest and most obvious way is to use nested switch statements.

```
   switch (month) {
          …
        case "08":
            switch (year) {
               case "15":
                 …
            }
            break;
          …
     }
```

Comment: That does literally answer their question, but let's be honest. They're not a developer (per their own statement) and so we should try to give them something that's easier on the eyes and brain to simplify the logic.